# Android how to use adapter for listView without extending listActivity

Tags: android, listview, adapter, listactivity

I have an application with tabs. In one tab I need to put data (strings) in rows. To do so I chose `tableLayout` but when I wanted to use a `contextmenu` on its rows it doesn't work.

I can show the `contextmenu` `onLongClick` but the problem is that I can't get the info about the selected row to edit or delete the selected row. Then I read in a discussion that using `listView` is better than `tablelayout` if we have many rows. But the examples I saw extend `listactivity` but I don't want to do this.

So when I try working on a `listView` without extending `listactivity` I don't know how to do it what I mean is that I've never used `listView` before so I try different examples I found on the internet to understand it but it's not working. Here's what I did so far for the `listView`:

```
String [] items=getRessources().getStringArray(R.arra.resolution);
 //Resolution is an array of strings
ListView lv=(ListeView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
v.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

When I compile it I get a list with elements of my array in it but first, I want to change the color of text which I can't. And secondly I want to add rows dynamically to the list which I don't know how to do either. I think I have to use an `adapter` to do it but I don't know how. 
Can someone please guide me through this. I just want to know how to attach my list to an `adapter` which'll allow me to dynamically add rows, add `contextMenu` etc.

Comment: Why don't you want to extend ListActivity?

Comment: @KasperMoerch actually I'm new to android dev and I'm already having trouble with some elements I thought it would create some more difficulties.

Comment: If you're using a `TabActivity`, each `Tab` will hold an `Activity`. If the `Activity` that holds the list you mention has this as its main purpose it would by far be easier to just extend `ListActivity`. If you don't want to do that, you need to implement your own custom `Adapter` in order to achieve the mentioned functionality (you will have to do this anyway, if you want to be able to add items to the list on the fly).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**main Activity class:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class SelectedActivity extends Activity {

private SelectedAdapter selectedAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.selected_example);

    // populate the model - a simple a list
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Apple");
    list.add("Orange");
    list.add("Grape");
    list.add("Grape1");
    list.add("Grape2");
    list.add("Grape3");
    list.add("Grape4");
    list.add("Grape5");
    list.add("Grape6");

    // create our SelectedAdapter
    selectedAdapter = new SelectedAdapter(this,0,list);
    selectedAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listExample);
    listview.setAdapter(selectedAdapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
            // user clicked a list item, make it "selected"
            selectedAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
        }
    });
}
```

**Adapter class:**

```
   import java.util.List;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class SelectedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

        // used to keep selected position in ListView
        private int selectedPos = -1;   // init value for not-selected

        public SelectedAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                       List objects) {
             super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }
        public void setSelectedPosition(int pos){
        selectedPos = pos;
             // inform the view of this change
             notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        public int getSelectedPosition(){
             return selectedPos;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                 View v = convertView;
                 // only inflate the view if it's null
                 // if (v == null) {
                        LayoutInflater vi =   (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.selected_row, null);
                 //  }

                 // get text view
                     TextView label = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtExample);
                     Button btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

                     // change the row color based on selected state
                     if(selectedPos == position){
                        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                        btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.next);
                     }
                     else{
                        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                     }

                     label.setText(this.getItem(position).toString());       
                     return(v);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer just one question what does selected_Row refer to in vi.inflate(R.layout.selected_row, null).

Comment: Same question for selected_example. Are these the layouts you've created? If yes what do they contain?

Comment: Ok I created two layouts: one with the listView and the other with the button and the testView and I get no compilation errors but nothing happens when I click a row. :s

Answer (score 0):

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg8"
    android:id="@+id/RootView"
    >
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/myLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
       </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You need to define an xml which will be used to hold data of each row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1">

   <TableRow
       android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
       android:layout_width="793dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="0.23" >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/col1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:width="50dp"
           android:textSize="18sp"

        />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/col2"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:width="150dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
        />
      <ImageView android:id="@+id/editimage"
            android:background="@drawable/edit"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="ClickHandlerForEditImage" 
            android:layout_width="35dp" 
         android:layout_height="35dp"/>  

    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

In the above xml i have also included the ImageView, it is not really required but this is just to update you that we can include the other controls also.

& at the last you should have a function in your related class:

```
private void LoadData()
{

    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    Cursor cur = db.GetData();
    private ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
    lv.setAdapter(null);
    if(cur.moveToFirst())
    {
            String[] from = new String[] {"_id","column1"};
            int[] to = new int[] {R.id.col1, R.id.col2};
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.grid_item, cur, from, to);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);  

     }
       db.close();
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that noone has answered you contextMenu question. To get a context menu to work with your list , after you call `ListView yourList = getListView();` you must call `registerForContextMenu(yourList);`

And to handle the menu creation you must implement the method

```
@Override public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){ 
super.onCreateContextMenu(context, v,menuInfo);
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
menu.setHeaderTitle("YOUR TITLE");
menu.setHeaderIcon(R.drawable.YOUR DRAWABLE);
inflater.inflate(R.menu.YOUR_MENU_RESOURCE, menu);
}
```

Then you can respond to clicks by implenting the method

```
@Override public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
switch(item.getItemId()){
case R.id.YOUR_MENU_ITEM: // do stuff if the item is selected
 return true;
case R.id.YOUR_MENU_ITEM: // do stuff if the item is selected
 return true;
case R.id.YOUR_MENU_ITEM: // do stuff if the item is selected
 return true;
 }
 return false; // nothing selected
}
```