# How could I use setViewImage in SimpleAdapter?

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap, simpleadapter

I will build a listview with images from the web. I've also asked an other question before: [Android ListView with images from special hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209748/android-listview-with-images-from-special-hashmap).
But now I tried to extend the SimpleAdapter. I use a hashmap to put the data. Then I use a new "ImageAdapter":

```
public class ImageAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

         public ImageAdapter(Context context,
                    List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from,
                    int[] to) {
                super(context, data, resource, from, to);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

         @Override
            public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) {
                super.setViewImage(v, value);
                URL url;
                try {
                    url = new URL(value);
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    v.setImageBitmap(bm);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

          }
```

My list.xml:

```
[...]
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip" />
[...]
```

There is no error - but the imageview is blank / white! How could I fill the imageview with the image defined in data (as String / URL):

```
ada = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data, R.layout.list, new String[] {"imgurl", "title", "date", "ex", "id"}, new int[] {R.id.list_image, android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2, R.id.text3});
```

Thanks for helping! I tried many variations...but nothing works :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to read this [tutorial](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2012/06/13/lazy-loading-images-from-urls-to-listviews/). You will learn about BaseAdapter, ViewHolder pattern and correct asynchronous image loading.