# How to use onclick button in baseAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, onclick

How to use on click event button in extend baseadapter.. I tried a lot but no use.. In my project there is custom listview, it contain text,button(btnlist), fastscroll index. when i onclick button(btnlist) it is not gng to other activity, no error is also displaying,no toast..
Plz help me with example . thank u in advance.

Quick ref: getview---> holder.btnList.setOnClickListener

EfficientAdapter.java

```
public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SectionIndexer, OnClickListener {
IndexableListView mListView;
private String mSections = "#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
ArrayList<Patient> patientListArray;

private Intent intent;
private Patient patient;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context context;
private int positions;
ViewHolder holder;


public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;

    String patientListJson = CountriesList.jsonData;
    JSONObject jssson;
    try {
        jssson = new JSONObject(patientListJson);
        patientListJson = jssson.getString("PostPatientDetailResult");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray Jarray = parser.parse(patientListJson).getAsJsonArray();
    patientListArray = new ArrayList<Patient>();
    for (JsonElement obj : Jarray) {
        Patient patientList = gson.fromJson(obj, Patient.class);
        patientListArray.add(patientList);
    //  Log.i("patientList", patientListJson);

    }
}


public int getCount() {

    return patientListArray.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {

    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    this.positions = position;      
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (rowView  == null) {                     
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homemplebrowview, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.text2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.mrn);
        holder.text3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.text4 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.age);
        holder.text5 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.gender);
        holder.text6 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.wardno);
        holder.text7 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.roomno);
        holder.text8 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.bedno);
        holder.btnList = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listbutton);
        /*Button editButton = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listbutton) ;
        editButton.setTag(position);
        editButton.setClickable(true);
        editButton.setOnClickListener(EfficientAdapter.this);
        rowView.setClickable(true);*/


        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text1.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getName()));
    holder.text2.setText(patientListArray.get(position).getMrnNumber());
    holder.text3.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getRoom()));
    holder.text4.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getAge()));
    holder.text5.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getGender()));
    holder.text6.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getWard()));
    holder.text7.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getRoom()));
    holder.text8.setText(Util.formatN2H(patientListArray.get(position)
            .getBed()));        
    holder.btnList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "STAT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
            Intent next = new Intent(context, SeviceDetails.class);
            Log.i("patient", " next "+ position + " onclickposition " + patientListArray.get(position).getMrnNumber());
            patient = getPatientDetailsByMrn(patientListArray, position);
            Log.i("DDDD ", patient.getMrnNumber());             
            next.putExtra("patient", patient);
            next.putExtra("position", position);
            System.out.println("patient"+ patient);
            context.startActivity(next);
        }
    });
return rowView;
}       

static class ViewHolder {
    public Button btnList;
    public TextView text8;
    public TextView text7;
    public TextView text6;
    public TextView text5;
    public TextView text4;
    public TextView text1;
    public TextView text2;
    public TextView text3;
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
    sortMyData();

    Log.i("getPositionForSection", "section" + section);
    // If there is no item for current section, previous section will be
    // selected
    for (int i = section; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < getCount(); j++) {
            if (i == 0) {

                Log.i("getPositionForSection- i", "section" + i);
                // For numeric section
                for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {

                    if (StringMatcher.match(
                            String.valueOf(patientListArray.get(j)
                                    .getName().charAt(0)),
                            String.valueOf(k)))
                        Log.i("getPositionForSection- j", "section" + j);

                        return j;
                }
            } else {
                if (StringMatcher.match(
                        String.valueOf(patientListArray.get(j).getName()
                                .charAt(0)),
                        String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(i))))
                    return j;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public Object[] getSections() {
    String[] sections = new String[mSections.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < mSections.length(); i++)
        sections[i] = String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(i));
    return sections;
}

/**
 * sorting the patientListArray data
 */
public void sortMyData() {
    // sorting the patientListArray data
    Collections.sort(patientListArray, new Comparator<Object>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object k1, Object k2) {
            Patient p1 = (Patient) k1;
            Patient p2 = (Patient) k2;
            return p1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getName());
        }

    });
}


     }
```

.xml

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/listbutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginRight="43dp"   
        android:focusable="false"      
        android:text="Episode"
        android:textColor="#666666" />
```

default listview

```
       <ListView 

         android:id="@+id/homelistView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:dividerHeight="0dip" />
```

Comment: does your button get selected when you press on it?

Comment: @carnel no boss onclick event is not working..

Comment: I know that on click event is not getting fired, but if the button doesn't get selected at all, try to set it as focusable in your xml file.

Comment: @Carnal button will get select but onclick is not working..

Comment: Hmm strange, are you sure that you have not set onClick = "someMethod()" in your xml for that button?

Comment: focusable = "false" should do it.

Comment: @Carnal check in 8th line, i add it..

Comment: @Carnal should i use default listview in xml.. for custom listview. any idea..

Comment: what do u mean by default list view?

Comment: @Carnal sorry i will add code above.

Comment: try to inflate like this instead:
vi.inflate(R.layout.homemplebrowview, null);

Comment: rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.homemplebrowview, null);

Comment: @Carnal no its working..

Comment: very strange man, because I've done this before with "BaseAdapter" and "ArrayAdapter" and for me it's working.

Comment: @carnal really yaar. can u send me whole code of custom list view with base adapter so i will compare it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use your Adapter to populate the list with the items. Then in your Activity or Fragment you should implement the `onListItemClick` event to handle the click on the list item.

EDIT: I am posting an example below where I am using a `ListFragment` - this is the piece of code I have available right now, I can post something specific to `ListView` later:

```
public class RecipiesActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private RecipiesSummaryListAdapter m_listAdapter; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* here you need to set the adapter of the listview 
           and do other things for your applicaiton (i.e. populate the 
           data in your adapter. In your case, since you are calling a 
           WS you want to do that in a different task */ 
        ListFragment lf = 
             (ListFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.my_list_fragment);
        lf.setListAdapter(m_listAdapter);
}
```

Then in your `ListFragment`:

```
/* imports and other things go here then... */ 
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.myListViewXml, 
                                           container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // put your handler here

    }   
}
```

For details on `ListFragment` see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html).

I think that a very nice example (although by extending `ArrayAdapter` instead of `BaseAdapter` is hown in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267060/android-how-to-use-adapter-for-listview-without-extending-listactivity).

There is one point to remember:

1. The button must not be focusable (i.e. in XML use `android:focusable="false"` - like you have in your XML).
2. You need to capture provide an `onItemClick` event handled as shown below (extract from the link above):

Code:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    //@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View view,
                                  int position, long id) {
        // user clicked a list item, make it "selected"
        selectedAdapter.setSelectedPosition(position);
        //Do your stuff here
}
```

Finally, note one point. This solution means that you click on the list row and the event gets fired.

I think that if you want the user to click on the button and the event to get fired on the button, then you need to set call `listview.setItemsCanFocus(true)` right after you inflate your ListView XML and make sure that the Button is `focusable` in the XML. Listening for the `onClick` event should work then.

This is described in Slide 25 of the GoogleIO World of ListView presentation (you can get it [here](http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf) and the [video is here](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html))

Hope this helps

Comment: sure.. plz update...dnt forget..i will try to add this code.. thanks for ur reply.

Comment: btw, if you set `android:focusable="false"` for the button (like you have), then touching the list item should fire the `onListItemClick` event. This should be fine unless you have more than one buttons on the list row.

Comment: **update (Corrected the event)** Note that the `onItemSelected` is on the ListView (not on the button) and it will include in the callback the postion clicked. Then use `getItemAtPosition` to get access to the specific item.

Answer (score 3):

try the following for your button:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score 3):

Write the `holder.btnList.setOnClickListener` inside the `if (rowView  == null)` condition and try again.

Answer (score 2):

use the following code in getView() Method:

```
    Button status = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        status.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_account);
        status.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                       // DO your stuff
            }
        });
```