# Add image in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I´d like to add an image in a row of a `ListView`, this is my code:

```
ListView listViewProducts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewProducts);
ImageView iconMeat = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iconMeat);

String[] products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.products);

for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < listViewProducts.getCount(); itemPos++)
{
    if ( products[0].equals(listViewProducts.getItemAtPosition(itemPos)) )
    {
        //TODO
        // In this case to add the image 
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: u need to use custom adapter

Comment: copy images into drawables folder, and create a string array as you did for products the same way for images and initialize array with drawable id like R.drawable.image1 R.drawable.image2 for every list row

Comment: You have to use a Custom Adapter. There you'll set the image object which src attribute will be overridden

Answer (score 1):

See these posts for using adapters in listview :-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8267165/2035885
http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Do following:-

1. Create a custom adapter for listview.
2. Create an array of drawables for populating the list.
3. In your getView method of adapter populate the list according to index.